# Will Trusty/14.04 Installation Media come without Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, 14.04

As [Ubuntu One has been shut down](http://blog.canonical.com/2014/04/02/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services/) now, and the current build of 14.04 'Trusty' still comes with Ubuntu One (and U1 Music, etc with it):

1. Would Ubuntu One come with the final release as well? Please check the [Trusty Release Schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseSchedule); the Final Beta was released on March 27.

   If it does, I think it'd lead to a huge confusion for users, and also embarrassment for people like me who'd have to tell new migrants (from the Windows world) that this service has now been shut down.
2. Also, as U1 is now dead, how would the users of the Phone version on Trusty sync their Contacts, Files, Music, etc?
3. Would 13.10 LIVE DVD images also be updated to incorporate this change?

Comment: I think I read that Trusty won't have U1 (Well, it wouldn't really make sense now, really).

Comment: Are you sure? The [Trusty Release Schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseSchedule) says that the Final Beta was out on March 27. Would they still remove the now-obsolete packages?

Comment: They probably knew they would take it out beforehand. But, I really don't know, it's just a guess.

Comment: I don't think so, else: 1. The shutdown news would have been posted earlier. 2. Users who'd have tried the earlier builds of Trusty (esp tech-mags and websites) would have published that Ubuntu One is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently using 14.04 and it doesn't have any of the U1 services.If you are upgrading from previous versions, they should be removed.

2 About contact/email/storage/music syncing its already been answered here
 [Ubuntu one FAQs](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/does-this-mean-there-will-be-no-contactemailstoragemusic-sync-for-ubuntu-phone-os/).

3 As 13.10 is not a LTS release, it will soon be dead. So the LIVE DVD images won't be updated.

Comment: No, upgrading from previous versions does not remove the packages. I'm also not sure why my answer (which already has 7 up votes) was un-accepted in favor of this answer, which is shorter and somewhat incorrect.

Comment: @dobey Thanks for your comment. 1. I upgraded to 14.04 too and all UbuntuOne packages were removed too. 2. The Q better answers the sync part, vis-a-vis Contacts & Ubuntu Phone although yours was good too. 3. I didn't un-accept your answer, I just accepted this one to answer my queries better (albeit shorter in length). I'm sorry if that hurt.

Comment: The packages were removed, because you chose to allow it (you probably didn't read the list of things being removed, and blindly said 'OK' when that came up). I clearly stated that in my answers.

Comment: @dobey I had checked that list, obviously. This answer too says "they should be removed". I don't say that your answer is incorrect. This one just answer the #2 a bit better. And when it came up, I checked the link and some of my doubts were cleared even further. So, I just accepted it. But, I did not un-accept your answer (neither did I want to). Sadly, AU allows only one answer to be accepted.

Answer (score 8):

The client packages for file sync have already been removed from the 14.04 archive, yes. However, if you upgrade, the client will not be removed unless you choose to allow it to be removed during the process.

Contacts sync has been shut down for a long time already. You are not using it on any current phone version of the client with Ubuntu One. Also, the phone apps did not support synchronization. You could only download individual files from the service. Only auto-upload was supported, only for photos. The music streaming app will stop working on June 1. The Android and iOS apps will be removed from the respective stores at some point.

The 13.10 install image will never change. However, 13.10 will also no longer be supported, after July 2014, and it is already impossible for new users to sign up for the service.

Comment: Are you sure? The [Trusty Release Schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseSchedule) says that the Final Beta was out on March 27. Would they still remove the now-obsolete packages?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. It's already done. Final Beta != final release. It means there will be no more betas, and ideally, that should be what's final, but things might still change.