# How to install Ubuntu One?

Tags: backup, cloud

How do I install "Ubuntu One" on Ubuntu 16.04? Although it seems trivial but I couldn't find nowhere instructions? I want to backup my files on cloud using Ubuntu One service. Also when I open Deja-dup for backup I cannot see "Save to Ubuntu One" option on storage location in settings?

Comment: @user535733 The duplicate candidate is closed as **"too broad"**. I don't think this question qualifies as too broad.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will Trusty/14.04 Installation Media come without Ubuntu One?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446576/will-trusty-14-04-installation-media-come-without-ubuntu-one)

Comment: @dobey The duplicate candidate makes very specific questions about Ubuntu **13.10** and **14.04** in regards to transition of **Ubuntu One** services. This question is about Ubuntu **16.04** and the answer the OP seeks can only be read between the lines of the duplicate candidate. The OP here wants to backup to the cloud and was mislead to believe Ubuntu One could do it.

Comment: It specifically questions whether Ubuntu One will continue to be included in Ubuntu releases, given the announcement that it will be shutting down, and the question includes a link to the announcement.

Answer (score 6):

As per [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_One):

> In April 2014, Canonical announced that the cloud storage and
>   synchronization features would be shut down at the end of July 31 of
>   2014, leaving the sign-on features intact.[4]

It would appear you need to find other cloud services for backup.

The same article lists other services that might interest you:

> The Ubuntu One service was similar to services such as Microsoft
>   OneDrive, iCloud, Dropbox, Google Play Music, Amazon Cloud Player. Its
>   client code was written in Python. It used Twisted for its low-level
>   networking and Protocol Buffers for protocol description. Data was
>   synced over a custom protocol called "u1storage", and stored on Amazon
>   S3.[8]